# Accessing non const method from const object

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

I have a C++ example where I try to set a property on a class member which is accessed through a const getter.

```
#include <iostream>

struct prop
{
    prop() : m_val {0} {}
    int val() const { return m_val; }
    void set_val(int v) { m_val = v; }
private:
    int m_val;
};

struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual prop property() const = 0;
    virtual void set_property(prop p) = 0;
};

struct derived : public base
{
    derived() : m_prop {prop {}} {}
    prop property() const { return m_prop; }
    void set_property(prop p) { m_prop = p; }
private:
    prop m_prop;
};

int main()
{
    base *d1 = new derived();
    d1->property().set_val(2);
    // prints 0
    std::cout << "property val: " << d1->property().val() << '\n';
    delete d1;

    base *d2 = new derived();
    auto p = d2->property();
    p.set_val(2);
    d2->set_property(p);
    // prints 2
    std::cout << "property val: " << d2->property().val() << '\n';
    delete d2;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this to give me an error on `d1->property().set_val(2);` because `property()` method is `const` and should give me a `const prop` object which doesn't have `set_val` method. But this compiles without any errors and the line `d1->property().set_val(2);` doesn't actually change the `val` as shown by the `cout` line. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Edit: I now understand the issue with `property()` returning non-const and by value and why that doesn't give a compiler error and doesn't change`d1`. The best solution in my use case was to make the return value of `property` to be `prop const&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `d1->property().set_val(2);` doesn't actually change the `val`

Because `property()` returns by value, that means what `property()` returns is a temporary object which is copied from the data member `m_prop`. Then `set_val` is called on the temporary object which is destroyed immediately.

> because `property()` method is `const` and should give me a `const prop` object

No. You declare the return type as `prop`, then it'll return a non-const `prop`. In the `const` `property()`, the data member `m_prop` becomes `const`, it's copied to the returned object which is non-const. The return type won't *become* to `const`.

I think you should change the return type to `const prop&` (in both `base` and `derived` class). Then you'll get the error expected. e.g.

```
const prop& property() const { return m_prop; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`property` returns a *copy* of `m_prop`, which is a modifiable, albeit temporary, value.  Because of that, you are not making any changes to `dl` and the value when printed out will still be the original value.

Answer (score 2):

That the method is `const` just means that calling it won't mutate the object you call it on.

The object you get back from the method (by value) is a brand new object and you can do to it what you want. It's in no way related to the object you got it from (except from being a copy of what the getter returned) or the `const`ness of the function you called to obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `property()` member function to return a `const prop` object, specify that it does so:

```
struct base{
    virtual const prop property() const=0;
};
```

As it stands, you get a non-`const` `prop` object which is *a copy* of the property. You can merrily set the values of that object but it won't affect the stored property value.